# "developer options not available for this user" Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm experiencing very interesting problem with my Galaxy S6 Edge phone with marshmallow. When I go to developer options. Instead of a long list of options I get a message of "developer options not available for this user". As far as I know, I don't have any other user (I even don't know how to add a user, to be honest). I saw a couple of people had a similar issue with kitkat but they weren't even able to get the developer options menu item in the settings. I have that developer options item and I actually have it for a while. I haven't done anything special recently and I wonder anyone experienced this before and whether there is a way of fixing this without factory reset.

Finally there are a couple of more symptoms which may/may not be related with this.
Task Switch button at the bottom of screen doesn't work.
The settings button on the notifications panel doesn't work

EDIT : I had to fix the issue by factory reset, I didn't have the chance to try Victor's answer but I am accepting it as the right answer since there are some people who were able to fix their issue

Comment: have you tried tapping 7 times in build number?

Comment: I did actually. It has no effect. Maybe since it is already enabled.

Comment: if you have already enable then it will toast print like you are already developer

Comment: btw which mobile are you using ?model number please

Comment: Hey, You are right actually it doesn't show the toast message.Model SM-G925T Tmobile version with 6.0.1 android version

Comment: It seems like only way out is factory reset and guess what it works every time!

Comment: Exactly same here (cm13 by chil360 for u8833 (huawei y300-0100)

Comment: Exactly the same problem on SM-T320 (mondrianwifi) with Lineage OS (Android 6.0.1) Also can't open tasks switcher.

Comment: Exactly same issue with Leeco Le 2 running on Android 6.0.1. All of a sudden a weird "mode" has got enabled which has firstly disabled the multitasking button and the middle button. Out of the 3 bottom buttons, only the back button is functional. Upon attempting to make calls, a "Dialup failed. Limit exceeded" shows up. Notifications are disabled and the notification drawer is also acting weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to run the *com.google.android.setupwizard/.SetupWizardTestActivity* activity and step through the setup wizard - https://plus.google.com/u/0/+PaulOBrien/posts/8EGNvpY9jQa

A relatively easy way of running that activity is described here: http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s7/659407-s7-edge-not-showing-notifications-tray-recent-apps-button-settings-button-dnt-work.html#post5083902

> 1) Download Nova Launcher & set it as default to replace TouchWiz.
>   2) Long press on the home screen.
>   3) Choose Widgets.
>   4) At the top, under Nova Launcher, scroll to the right & press & hold on Activities and place it somewhere empty on the home screen.
>   5) Scroll down to Setup Wizard. I saw 2 Setup Wizard options.
>   6) Under the first Setup Wizard option, I opened it & scrolled down to the 3rd choice which said ".SetupWizardTestActivity". It might be in a different spot for you, but look at the small writing, that's how I saw this one.
>   7) Select that to create the widget shortcut.
>   8) Open it. Apparently you're supposed to have a menu to go through and just click through "Next", but there wasn't one for me.

Following the instructions in that forum post fixed the problem on my Note 4.

Comment: Thanks, I faced same issue in moto g3 and this post worked for me without loss data. "Nova Louncher best !"

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This has already worked on two different phones for me.

Comment: I only have one "Setup Wizard" with one option under it at step 5: ".carrier.ActivationActivity". Selecting that doesn't seem to help. :(

Comment: @takteek, could you solve your problem? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by adding and then deleting a new user:

1. In Settings, go to "Users".
2. Tap "Add user" and follow the prompts, including "Set up now" to switch to the new user.
3. Repeat step #1.
4. Tap your original user to switch back.
5. Repeat step #1.
6. Tap the gear icon next to the new user, then tap "Remove user" and follow the prompts.

Comment: Also tried this answer but when I tap "Users" nothing happens. :(